# Exibir elementos de array associativo com foreach

Tags: php, array, array-associativo

Olá, pessoal. Gostaria de exibir os elementos de um array associativo da seguinte forma:

```
Nome: José
Idade: 32
Profissão: Médico

Nome: Rafaela
Idade: 28
Profissão: Dentista
```

Tudo isso na mesma página. 
E o código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
<?php
    $usuarios = array(
                    array("nome"=>"José", "idade"=>32, "profissao"=>"Médico"),
                    array("nome"=>"Rafaela", "idade"=>28, "profissao"=>"Dentista"),
                    array("nome"=>"Gabriela", "idade"=>18, "profissao"=>"Não tem")
                );

    foreach ($usuarios as $informacoes => $dados){
        echo $informacoes . " : ";
        echo $dados;
    }
?>
```

Mas, com este código, eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
0 : 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Development/PHP/Exercicio9/usuarios.php on line 10
Array1 : 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Development/PHP/Exercicio9/usuarios.php on line 10
Array2 : 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Development/PHP/Exercicio9/usuarios.php on line 10
Array
```

Pesquisando, percebi que para mostrar o array seria necessário dar um `print_r` ao invés do `echo`, mas este comando mostra literalmente o array.
Gostaria de saber se é possível e como eu posso fazer para exibir os índices e os respectivos valores do array da forma que mostrei.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop dentro do outro:

```
 $usuarios = array(
                    array("nome"=>"José", "idade"=>32, "profissao"=>"Médico"),
                    array("nome"=>"Rafaela", "idade"=>28, "profissao"=>"Dentista"),
                    array("nome"=>"Gabriela", "idade"=>18, "profissao"=>"Não tem")
                );
foreach($usuarios as $informacoes) {
  foreach($informacoes as $chave => $valor) {
    echo $chave;
    echo ': ';
    echo $valor;
    echo '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada, jHertel, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou um array associativo dentro de outro array assossiativo, tenta usar esse codigo:

```
<?php

    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

        $usuarios = array(
                        array("nome"=>"José", "idade"=>32, "profissao"=>"Médico"),
                        array("nome"=>"Rafaela", "idade"=>28, "profissao"=>"Dentista"),
                        array("nome"=>"Gabriela", "idade"=>18, "profissao"=>"Não tem")
                    );

        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario){
            echo "Nome : " . $usuario['nome'] . "<br>";
            echo "Idade :" . $usuario['idade'] . "<br>";
            echo "Profissao :" . $usuario['profissao'] . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Eric, obrigada pela ajuda, mas esse código funciona, eu já tinha testado ele. Eu quero saber com array associativo como funciona, entende? Quero saber como posso mostrar a chave e o dado do array ao mesmo tempo usando o foreach.

Comment: Se eu entedi o que vc quer e so fazer assim:


foreach ($usuarios as $key => $value) 
{ echo "{$key} => {$value} "; }